# mssql-server installation without root or sudo access

Tags: software-installation

How to install a program without `root`/`sudo` `access` in `Ubuntu 16.04`? I want to install `mssql-server vnext`. I tried by:

```
APT_CACHE_DIR="./.app/cache"
APT_STATE_DIR="./.app/state"
mkdir -p "$APT_CACHE_DIR/archives/partial"
mkdir -p "$APT_STATE_DIR/lists/partial"
APT_OPTIONS="-o debug::nolocking=true -o dir::cache=$APT_CACHE_DIR -o dir::state=$APT_STATE_DIR"
apt-get $APT_OPTIONS update
```

Comment: Use another operating system that is not based on Linux?  We use sudo. Any other Linux system not using sudo will require root. If you do not own the system ask the admin to install it for you.

Answer (score 0):

When you install a software, you will always need to use sudo because you are making changes in the system. In your case you can do the following, find a portable version of mysql(which doesn't exist) or compile the software from source. Installing software this way is not ideal as it doesn't blend well with your system. You can try something like this but be warned that you would have to resolve all dependencies by yourself:

```
apt-get source package
cd package
./configure --prefix=$HOME
make
make install
```